# How to differentiate the call from filter angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<li>
     <p>By Member Status</p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter['top']"> top</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter['low']"> low</label></p>
                </li>
<li>
                    <p>By ADMIN Status</p>
                    <select class="form-control" ng-init="selectedSearch = 'default'">
                        <option value="default">Select Status</option>
                        <option value="A" ng-model="filter['a']">A</option>
                         <option value="B" ng-model="filter['b']">B</option>
                    </select>
                </li>

    <div class="complete-profile" ng-class="{active:show}" ng-repeat="mylist in mylist | filter:filterByCategory"></div>

  $scope.filterByCategory = function (stat) {
       return $scope.filter[stat.state] || noFilter($scope.filter); // checkbox
    };
$scope.filterByCategory = function (stat) {
       return $scope.filter[stat.drop] || noFilter($scope.filter); // dropdown
    };
```

i need to apply both filter on mylist but somehow one one filter works either for checkbox or dropdown both never works.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your filtering logic. [Code here](http://jsfiddle.net/biosis/cg7n7sb3/24/)

```
...
$scope.filter = {
    top: false,
    low: false,
    byAdminStatus: 'A'
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared `$scope.filterByCategory` twice.  Because JavaScript [variable names must be unique](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp), the first declaration will be overwritten by the second.

I suggest giving each filter its own meaningful name.  Then, you can [chain the filters together](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/filters/chaining-filters-together.html) to produce the composite filtering:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in mylist | filter:filterByState | filter:filterByDrop">
```

Here is an example of using multiple filters on a `ng-repeat`: http://jsfiddle.net/2671uggu/